# RPC TCP GO выход из программы

Tags: golang, tcp, rpc

Я реализовал простой клиент-серверное приложение на Golang с помощью rpc. Хотел узнать можно ли каким нибудь образом настроить так, чтобы к примеру со стороны клиента отправляем сообщение "Выход", то соединение закрывалось и клиент и сервер тоже закрывались.
Код сервера:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
    "net/rpc"
)

type Listener int

func (l *Listener) GetLine(line []byte, ack *bool) error {
    fmt.Println(string(line))
    return nil
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Запуск сервера...")
    addy, err := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp", "0.0.0.0:3001")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    inbound, err := net.ListenTCP("tcp", addy)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    listener := new(Listener)
    rpc.Register(listener)
    rpc.Accept(inbound)
}
```

Код клиента:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "log"
    "net/rpc"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    client, err := rpc.Dial("tcp", "localhost:3001")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    in := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    for {
        line, _, err := in.ReadLine()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        var reply bool
        err = client.Call("Listener.GetLine", line, &reply)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А чем простой вызов [`Close`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/rpc/#Client.Close) у клиента не устраивает?

Comment: При вызове Close я не могу потом дальше отправлять сообщения, т.е. одно сообщение и сразу выходит из программы

Comment: Эм... Ну вы же закрыли соединение. Логично, что после этого надо ещё раз вызвать `Dial` для установления нового соединения.

Comment: Я имел ввиду, что изначально могу отправлять сколько угодно сообщений, но хочу чтобы соединение закрылось после определенного сообщения. А если я вызываю Close, то у меня сразу же после любого сообщения соединение закрывается

Comment: То есть вам нужно закрыть соединение со стороны сервера?